# If new active record has attributes, then create a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `DoSomething` model. This model allows super users to tell other users to do something at a certain time.

I want to allow super users to a send either or:

1. a reminder to the other users to do the `DoSomething` 30 minutes before the `DoSomething`
2. a reminder to the other users to do the `DoSomething` 2 hours after the `DoSomething`.

On the `DoSomething` model I have booleans for the reminders.

Once the `DoSomething` is created I want to check if either of the reminders are true, and if so send a reminder from the `DoSomething` model.

I'd like to know the mechanism for checking each of the reminders and then creating the reminders.
The reminders will be a has_many relationship on the `DoSomething` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only concerned about creating reminders when a DoSomething is created, then the below should work:

```
class DoSomething < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reminders
  before_create :issue_reminders_if_needed

  private

  def issue_reminders_if_needed
    return unless boolean_1 || boolean_2

    # Code to create reminders goes here
  end
end
```